# cannot find where event is being raised from

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I Create a function NewLoad() and call it in butto1_click.
And i have event listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged which called itself during operation function "NewLoad"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewLoad();
}

private void NewLoad()
{
    String text = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    textBox1.Text = text;
    oleDbSelectCommand1.Parameters[0].Value = text;

    dataSet11.Clear(); <<<--- call listbox1_SelectedIndexChanged

    oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet11);
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataSet21.Clear();
}
```

why this happens and how i can to avoid it?

Comment: Read the call stack in the debugger.

Comment: > AutoService.exe!AutoService.Form1.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 53 ---- it's all.. where this event is call?

Comment: Disable Just My Code and look again.

Comment: You should name your controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that the listbox is databound to the dataset.

When you clear your dataset, the listbox is emptied, and the selection changes.
This raises the relevant event.

Comment: thk, i understand.. but now i have another problem..)

Answer (score 0):

If you have something selected in list box 1, when you clear it, the selected index will change, thus raising selection changed event.